Получить атрибут href при наведении на ссылку
Даны ссылки. Сделайте так, чтобы по наведению на любую ссылку над ней появлялось значение ее атрибута href.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="dasdas">asdasd</a>
  <a href="dasdasddas">asdasasdasd</a>
  <a href="dasdasdasdas">asdasasdasd</a>
  <script>
    let href = document.querySelector('a')
    document.body.onmouseenter = function(e) {
      let traget = e.target
      console.log(traget.getAttribute('href')) // получаю значение, но с null

      // здесь я остановился и не могу понять как вывести значение атрибута>

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



Перечитал главу про события мыши, но все равно не могу понять. Нужно реализовывать через :hover?

Добавьте console.log(traget); увидите причину


Сделайте так, чтобы по наведению на любую ссылку над ней появлялось значение ее атрибута href

Можно на CSS :)


a:hover {
  position: relative;
}

a:hover::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(href);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #000;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
<br><br>
<a href="dasdas">asdasd</a>
<a href="https://site.com/dasdasddas">asdasasdasd</a>
<a href="dasdasdasdas">asdasasdasd</a>




спасибо. Ваше решение, по сути, решает задачу. В условии не говорится, что нужен онли жс. Просто задачник по жс)

Давайте разбираться, в самом вопросе обработчик onmouseenter, привязан к document.body, он не будет работать как ожидается потому что срабатывает только один раз, когда курсор входит в область body, потому он не будет работать для отдельных ссылок. Можно было бы оставить document.body но сменить событие на mouseover и использовать делегирование:


const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    tooltip.textContent = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';

    const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    tooltip.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
    tooltip.style.top = (rect.top - tooltip.offsetHeight) + 'px';
  }
});

document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="dasdas">asdasd</a>
  <a href="dasdasddas">asdasasdasd</a>
  <a href="dasdasdasdas">asdasasdasd</a>

  <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
</body>

</html>




Спасибо. А вот как сделать, чтобы при наведении выводился этот атрибут именно через js. На css это реализуемо и De.Minov продемонстрировал. Мой вариант на ссс тоже. А с js всю голову сломал

@alexWithoutBeard обновил ответ, правда я не знаю, предполагает ли это возможность использования дополнительного элемента, я использую <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip"></div> в качестве плейсхолдера.

спасибо большое за такой развёрнутый ответ


Перечитал главу про события мыши, но все равно не могу понять. Нужно реализовывать через :hover?

Видно не совсем внимательно читал... Вот так такое можно реализовать.


document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(o => o.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  const o = e.target
  if (o.getAttribute('title')) return
  o.setAttribute('title', o.getAttribute('href'))
}))
<a href="dasdas">asdasd</a>
<a href="dasdasddas">asdasasdasd</a>
<a href="dasdasdasdas">asdasasdasd</a>




Спасибо. А но как сделать чтобы при наведении выводился этот атрибут именно через js. С css можно. Есть вариант от De. Minov. Есть мой, но я его не покажу, ибо он кривой)

@alexWithoutBeard, сейчас он выводится в консоль "именно через js"... А ты куда собрался его выводить?

Согласно заданию, при наведении на ссылку атрибут href нужно выводить над ссылкой.

@alexWithoutBeard, тогда удобнее всего использовать css вариант для этого дела.

@alexWithoutBeard, добавил еще вариант с title... Навел, подержал - появилась подсказка...
